# Facing error in changing a guzzle code from guzzle 5 to guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

GuzzleHttp\Client::send() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface, instance of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response given

Have tried by making modification with no luck.

```
$request = $client->request('GET', $url, [
  'timeout' => 15,
  'exceptions' => false,
  'keepalive' => true
]);

$response = $client->send($request);
$body = $response->getBody();
$content = $body ? $body->getContents() : '';
$code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

i expect the send request to be successfully sent. However due to changes in guzzle 6 it is not working as expected.

Comment: what do you mean by not working as expected? Are you getting any error or are you not getting the expected response? please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `->send()` manually, the actual request is already done inside `->request()`. That why you see `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response` in the error.

So just remove the send line and you are done.

```
$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
  'timeout' => 15,
  'exceptions' => false,
  'keepalive' => true
]);

$body = $response->getBody();
$content = $body ? $body->getContents() : '';
$code = $response->getStatusCode();
```